# NoReverseMatch at /admin/app/model/ - Admin change_list.html

Tags: django-templates, django-admin

I don't know why I get this error while trying to reach the admin `change_list` page of the `mymodel` model:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/myapp/mymodel/
Reverse for 'myapp_mymodel_change' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Error during template rendering
In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 91

84        <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% if cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>{% csrf_token %}
85        {% if cl.formset %}
86          <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>
87        {% endif %}
88  
89        {% block result_list %}
90            {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
91            {% result_list cl %}
92            {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
93        {% endblock %}
94        {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
95        </form>
```

The error does not occur on my local runserver(Python 2.7.5, Django 1.5.1), only when deployed on my remote server (Python 2.7.2+, Django 1.5.1). Interestingly enough, only one specific model is affected by this -- I can reach the `change_list` pages of all the other models without any problems whatsoever. The rest of the admin area works fine as well.

The answers to similar questions regarding the `NoReverseMatch` error didn't help much because it happens in the admin, not my own code. Does anyone know where to start looking?

**EDIT:**

I had some customised `list_display` fields which I now commented out for testing. They seemed to be responsible for the `NoReverseMatch` error. Now I got another error instead:

```
AttributeError at /admin/myapp/mymodel/
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I then stripped away everything that isn't necessary. This is now my complete `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import *

class MymodelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['email', 'user', 'is_active', 'first_used']
    date_hierarchy = 'first_used'
    ordering = ['-first_used']
    list_filter = ['is_active', 'first_used', 'user']

admin.site.register(Mymodel, MymodelAdmin)
```

And on my local machine it still works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are some variables which are not getting passed during rendering the template .. 
Take your lead by checking the required local variables to be passed as to fulfill the url pattern in url tag ..

Comment: The only variables I see in ``django.contrib.admin.options.get_urls`` are ``info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.module_name``, ``url(r'^(.+)/$', wrap(self.change_view), name='%s_%s_change' % info),``. Since it is not my own code, I don't know what else to pass in there (and how). Could you clarify?

Comment: `NoReverseMatch at /admin/myapp/mymodel/
Reverse for 'myapp_mymodel_change' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`   show that you have not arguments or keyword arguments . Can you paste your admin python code .. ??

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem when my foreign key is null while using this script not originally mine on my admin change_list.html.

What it does is to display the column for foreign_key of your model.

```
from django.forms import MediaDefiningClass

class ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass(MediaDefiningClass):
def __getattr__(cls, name):

    def foreign_key_link(instance, field):          
        # Please note in Django 1.6
        # Model._meta.module_name was renamed to model_name           
        target = getattr(instance, field)
        return u'<a href="../../%s/%s/%d">%s</a>' % (             
            target._meta.app_label, target._meta.model_name, target.id, unicode(target)) 

    if name[:8] == 'link_to_':
        method = partial(foreign_key_link, field=name[8:])
        method.__name__ = name[8:]
        method.allow_tags = True
        setattr(cls, name, method)
        return getattr(cls, name)
    raise AttributeError
```

I added a line **`if target:`** in filter out those null values.

```
if target:
    return u'<a href="../../%s/%s/%d">%s</a>' % (             
      target._meta.app_label, target._meta.model_name, target.id, unicode(target))
```

**Script usage:**
    where carrier,sitename are a foreign key field.

```
class LatestRsl_v2Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    __metaclass__ = classmaker(right_metas=(ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass,))
    list_display        = ['issued', 'link_to_carrier', ]                           
    search_fields       = ['=rslno','=issued','link_to_carrier', 'link_to_sitename']
```